# destroying pointed-to object explicitly with decltype

Tags: c++, c++11

I have:

```
T* p;
```

and I'd like to do:

```
p->~decltype(*p)();
```

However, it doesnt work.

```
p->~T();
```

does work, but it like to do it with `decltype()`, if possible.

Error message:

```
error: expected class-name before 'decltype'
```

EDIT: use case

I'm trying to avoid the use of VLA for an array allocated on the stack using alloca + placement new of the array. After the placement new, the objects in the stack array need to be explicitly destroyed. I know how to solve the problem, I can do:

```
using T = ::std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*p)>;
p->~T();
```

But, I'm puzzled why this is necessary.

Comment: `decltype(*p)` is `T &`, not `T`. Even if you got the syntax to be accepted, it still wouldn't work.

Comment: Doesn't make any sense. It won't be same as calling a function anymore. Can you brief on the use case ?

Comment: I'm curious, what does `alloca` bring you that VLAs don't? `alloca` is just as non-standard as VLAs and VLAs at least have compiler support to properly handle exceptions and to automatically construct and destroy as needed. Is there some other important difference?

Comment: for some reason, clang choked on the VLA, but not on alloca and gcc works with both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're misunderstanding `decltype`. You need a non-reference type for the pseudo-destructor call.

Try this:

```
int * p = new int;
p->~decltype(declprval<decltype(*p)>())();
```

This is using:

```
template <typename T> std::decay_t<T> declprval();
```

Getting the decayed type of an expression out of a *decltype-specifier* is hard work. In "real code", I'd just use:

```
int * p = new int;
{
    using T = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*p)>;
    p->~T();
}
```

Comment: Note: the standard library's `std::declval` produces a glvalue, not a prvalue, so it's not suitable for this trick.

Answer (score 3):

What about something like:

```
template<typename T>
void call_destructor(T* obj)
{
    obj->~T();
}
```

This can be used as follows:

```
SomeClass* p = new SomeClass();
<...>
call_destructor(p);
```

Comment: very nice, but is there something available in the STL?

Comment: @user1095108 [`std::destroy_at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/destroy_at) in C++17